# boolean expression not working

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I have this code below:

```
boolean isInvisible = false;

public void onLoveButtonClicked(View view) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView);
    if (isInvisible){
        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

and

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/text"
    android:id="@+id/TextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Button1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

When I run the app and I press the button, the text shows up, but when I press again, it does nothing.

EDIT: `boolean isInvisible = false;`

Comment: You didn't show us the logic for `isInvisible`...

Comment: i edited it to false.

Comment: where you change value for false? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `textView.getVisibility()` to toggle Visibility of TextView as:

```
if (textView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE){
        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);            
    } else {
        textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe toggle your variable `isInvisible` as well?

```
 boolean isInvisible;

 public void onLoveButtonClicked(View view) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView);
    if (isInvisible){
        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);            
    } else {
        textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);            
    }
    isInvisible = !isInvisible;
}
```